# How to calculate the success (1,0) of a factor level?

Tags: r

#### Hi, I want to calculate the "prevalence" (presence of "success" / total individuals) by factor level.

So far I have found how to calculate it for all the data, but I want to do it for each level of the factor.

```
length(which(data$success==1))/nrow(data)*100
```

Comment: You can use `mean(data$success==1)`

Comment: I don't want to calculate the average, I want to calculate the "prevalence" (presence of "success" / total individuals) for each level of a factor.

Comment: Here the `mean` does that because it is the `mean` of a logical vector

Comment: Ok, but how can I calculate it by level of factor  and not generally as your example.

Comment: Try `tapply` or `by` or `aggregate` or `dplyr::group_by` or ...